# Proving equality of sets with equal cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If i have two finite sets $A$ and $B$ such that their cardinality is same and $A\subseteq B$ then prove $A=B$

This seems to be an obvious thing but i am having a hard time constructing a formal proof. Can anyone provide hints?

Comment: The statement is false, unless the sets are finite. Unfortunately, not all sets are finite, in a sense, almost none of them are.

Comment: Why not, though? I built a career around that concept. I guess I've been doing something meaningless...

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you provide a hint for the proof in the finite case??

Comment: I suggest induction on  the cardinality of $B$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I’m curious what you mean by “in a sense, almost none of them are”. Where can I learn about this?

Comment: @Seeker: Every set is a subset of an infinite set, and once you have an infinite subset you are infinite. So being finite defines an ideal of sets on the universe of sets. If filters formalise the notion of "almost everything", ideals formalise "almost nothing". So in a sense, most sets are infinite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I’ll have to learn what “ideals” and “filters” mean. But it sounds interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set. If there is an $f: X\to X$ which is injective but not surjective, we claim that $X$ is infinite. To see this, take $x \in X$ which is not in the image $f[X]$. We claim that each of the elements $x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))),\dots$ is distinct. If not, let's denote $f_n(x) = f(f(\cdots(f(x))))$ to be the result of $n$ applications of $f$ to $x$ and suppose that there are $m, n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $f_m(x) = f_n(x)$ and $m \neq n$. Without loss of generality, suppose $m < n$. By injectivity applied $m$ times we have $x = f_{n-m}(x) = f(\text{something in } X)$. But note that $x \not\in f[X]$, so that this is impossible. Hence if $X$ admits an injection $f: X\to X$ which isn't surjective then it must be infinite.

Let's use this to answer your original question. Suppose towards a contradiction that $A, B$ are finite sets of the same cardinality and $A \subseteq B$ with $A \neq B$. Then there's a bijection $f: B\to A$. As $A \neq B$, the natural inclusion $\iota: A \to B$ given by $\iota(x) = x$ is injective, but not surjective. So then $\iota \circ f$ is a non-surjective injection from $B$ to itself, contradicting finiteness of $B$. Ergo $A = B$.

(Really, this is a proof that a set is infinite if it is in bijection with a proper subset; hence if $B$ is finite and in bijection with a subset then that subset must actually be all of $B$.)